# Tasks Which are "Scheduled and waiting to run" Are Not Running

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a .net framework 4.6.1 aspnet MVC application which use to work until I updated a number of Nuget packages. I have backed out of most of the key packages and the issue is not fixed. Basically when my application hangs I can see a call to GetListAsync is made and never returns. This is a call to a SQL server using Dapper ORM which I have gone back to a known good version and this does not fix the issue. Looking at the tasks list it would appear to me I have 7 awaiting tasks and 5 tasks which are ready to run but for some reason they are not being scheduled. Looking at my worker ThreadPool I can see I have a good number of threads available and in fact this issue reproduces whenever I just start my aspnet application in dev and there is zero load on the app other than the first request. Any ideas why I would have a number of Scheduled Tasks which never seem to be picked up even if I wait a long period of time?

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to show the relevant code

Comment: I will try to pull in the relevant code - or at least the code I see that hangs. Not clear however why the code would help if the Tasks infrastructure is not scheduling tasks to run, but that may be my lack of knowledge here not being able to connect the dots.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this situation when I had a UI thread with

```
while (true)
{
   var message = await Console.In.ReadLineAsync();
   //some message processing
}
```

and some of another async methods have been called without await.
And I solved this problem with two ways:

Replace all async void to async Task and awaiting all async methods. But this not solved issue with blocking UI thread

And just run

```
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var message = await Console.In.ReadLineAsync();
           //some message processing
        }
    }
```

in another thread.